# Flex, HBox: how to horizontally center all children?

Tags: apache-flex

I cannot center the components in my VBox. I would like to set the standard css element "align: center". How can I do that in Flex ?

```
<mx:VBox>
    <mx:LinkButton label="Tag1" />
    <mx:Image source="@Embed(source='../icons/userIcon.png')" />
    <mx:Label id="username" text="Nickname" visible="false" fontWeight="bold"   />
</mx:VBox>
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, you can do this:

```
<mx:VBox width="200" horizontalAlign="center">
    <mx:Label text="foo" />
</mx:VBox>
```

I just tried this example, and it worked fine.  If the container's width is being dictated by its children, it might not appear to align correctly:

```
<mx:VBox horizontalAlign="center" borderStyle="solid">
    <mx:Label text="foo" />
    <mx:Label text="bar" />
</mx:VBox>
```

However, further specifying the width shows this attribute to work:

```
<mx:VBox width="200" horizontalAlign="center" borderStyle="solid">
    <mx:Label text="foo" />
    <mx:Label text="bar" />
</mx:VBox>
```

Comment: I wonder if the VBox width is being set by its children.  Try this: make the VBox width about 2x what you expect, and see if the 'horizontalAlign' works.

Comment: Sorry, it worked. My fault. The image is still not really centered. Is there any way to set an horizontal offset on it ? thanks